# Proper way to access a view with a list on Couchbase

Tags: list, view, couchbase

Using Couchbase 2.0 dp4 on a Mac

Trying to use a list to further filter my view. At this point I am simply trying to get any list to work with my view. So far all I can get is: {"error":"unknown_error","reason":"undef"};

Here is my design document:

```js
 {
    "_id": "_design/AllScopes",
    "_rev": "6-48c8555a",
    "views": {
    "AllScopes": {
        "map": "function(doc) {\n\n  if (doc.scope.search(/^\\{?[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\\}?$/i) >= 0)\n  {\n    var obj = {};\n    obj[doc.key] = doc.value;\n    emit(doc.scope, obj );\n  }\n\n}",
        "reduce": "function(keys, values, rereduce) { ..removed..}"
    }
},
"lists": {
    "ListScopes": "function(head, req) {\n  var row;\n  start({\n    \"headers\": {\n      \"Content-Type\": \"text/html\"\n     }\n  });\n  while(row = getRow()) {\n    send(row.value);\n  }\n}"
}
```

}

When I query my view with: localhost:8092/default/_design/AllScopes/_view/AllScopes?group=true

results in:

```js
{"rows":[
{"key":"016f77d2-dd42-41b4-98e7-50daa14d9e02","value":{"row":"b2f31852-a864-4680-9242-487181844b31","parent":{"_type":"Scope","_id":"ea45da3e-5c91-4ef2-b64e-0158a0c83e79","_template":{"_type":"Template","_path":"_level2.trylistorview","_mode":"server"}},"mode":"edit","g":"4592f903-7815-4e6c-97be-503626c6628c","_template":"_level2.views","_childname":"views","_activefield":"viewname","_active":false}},
{"key":"026bdb98-52eb-4986-a5c1-a0bfaf928af0","value":{"row":"44ff7ff1-c49b-407e-832b-2777dc69f288","parent":{"_type":"Scope","_id":"676b7fea-8cc8-4e7f-a232-f055ad142b58","_template":{"_type":"Template","_path":"_template","_mode":"server"}},"mode":"edit","g":"4592f903-7815-4e6c-97be-503626c6628c","_template":"_template","_activefield":"options","_active":false}}
....
]}
```

Then try to use the list with view using - localhost:8092/default/_design/AllScopes/_list/ListScopes/AllScopes?group=true.

All I can get is the unknown error above. I have tried different list function code and different url configurations but all fail. This list function is from an example found here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later

Any assistance in how to get a simple list working with a view would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Couchbase supports lists at the moment, but it is a feature that will be added in the future. Couchbase and CouchDB share a lot in common, but they are not fully compatible with one another.

Comment: I made the assumption it was available after I saw some comments that seemed to indicate it was pretty much the same features as CouchDB. Hopefully it is added soon. Thanks!